# Vaadin pass parameter to view

Tags: java, spring-boot, vaadin, vaadin8

I am currently making a form for film database, using Vaadin. My problem is the whole situation with deep linking. I want to have a url with an id of movie in it, to make possible to get to the form of concrete movie.

```
localhost:port/filmView/idOfSelectedMovie
```

I am currently using pushState but there are couple of problems.

1) When I add string "Film/" before Id, the first selection works fine, however with following selections the url just keeps adding this.

`http://localhost:8081/Film/Film/Film/Film/Film/4`

2) The second option I tried was using just an id. The effect was that the url just keeps the host with port, and gets rid of ViewName

```
http://localhost:8801/4
```

I had already tried to use replaceState and Urifragment methods, the effect wasn't better at all.

the function handling selection of movie on the list

```
 this.itemsList.addSelectionListener(selectionEvent -> {
            if (selectionEvent.getFirstSelectedItem().isPresent()) {
                Film selectedFilm = selectionEvent.getFirstSelectedItem().get();
                this.setupForm(selectedFilm);
                Page.getCurrent().pushState("Film/" + selectedFilm.getFilmId());

            }
        });
```

Comment: which version of Vaadin are you using?

Comment: I am currently using vaadin 8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have to do while navigating between views this: let's say you have a `View` with a list of films, from you can select a film. When you select a film from that list, you move to the film `View`

```
getUI().getNavigator().navigateTo(FilmView + "/" + filmId); //let's say id 88
```

in this way, you will navigate to `http://localhost:8081/Film/88`

now, in your `FilmView` you can get and use this id, something like:

```
public class FilmView extends VerticalLayout implements View{
    @Override
    public void enter(ViewChangeEvent event) {
        String yourPassedId = event.getParameters();
        //do stuff with your id, for example loading from DB
    }
}
```

In this way, you can reach every film you want with hard link, like `http://localhost:8081/Film/88`

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I must admit that I forget to mention that the navigator already serves moving between different types of forms. I have forms for three different kinds of items: films, countries, languages. Each have a View with list of items and master-detail form

Comment: glad to hear :)